# Managing Client Server

Tags: web-development-server

As a person aspiring to be a web developer, I've always wondered.

If you ask your client for payment do you include monthly payment for the server cost, or you just have a server of your own and it's a one time pay, or even you tell the client to pay the monthly fee by themselves?

Thanks beforehand for viewing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you negotiate with them. You might include hosting, you might resell hosting, they might arrange their own hosting or you may act as a middleman for arranging hosting and pass off the admin to them after the initial set up.

… but don't offer them lifetime hosting for a fixed price or one-off payment.

Comment: So we need to keep in contact with so many clients then, I'm planning to have multiple domain in my heroku account, is it a good idea?

How much is the average monthly charge for the client?

Comment: You need to keep in contact with any client that you want to continue taking money from. I have no idea what sort of services heroku offer. The average monthly charge depends on the services being offered and geographical location (and more specific discussion on that subject treads a bit too close to laws surrounding price fixing for comfort)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I guess it's kinda a chore becoming a webdev.

Comment: It is a chore being a freelancer. If you work for an agency, then they take care of all that. If you work in the web dept. of a company then there aren't any clients to stay in touch with.